# summing column up on row condition in SQL

Tags: postgresql, sum

I have a column named 'Name' with categorical data, and another column named 'Total' with the total in each category.

I want to sum up the total of few grouped Names:

eg: Name(apple, banana, celery, beans);  Total(300, 408, 350, 250)
I want to compute the sum of fruits i.e sum(apple +bananas) & vegetables sum(celery+beans)  separately.

How do I do this is Postgre SQL

Comment: If your PostgreSQL version >= 9.4 you can use `FILTER` clause: [Aggregate Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) In your case it would be `... sum(total) filter (where name in ('apple', 'banana')) as total_fruits, ...`

Answer (score 2):

Try Conditional `SUM`

```
 SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN Name IN ('apple', 'banana', 'celery', 'beans') THEN Total
                                                                      ELSE 0
             END) AS ap_ba_ce_be_total,

        SUM( CASE WHEN Name IN ('apple', 'banana') THEN Total
                                                   ELSE 0
             END) AS ap_ba_total 
 FROM YourTable
```